# How to deploy an on-demand GPU heavy VM instance on GCP in a nutshell?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a GPU-heavy image processing workload (A Python script that takes in a few hundred images) that I need to deploy on GCP. What is the easiest way to do this? Do I need to containerize the application? Is there a AWS Lambda-equivalent version on GCP that allows me to run a Python script fast & easily with minimal configuration? Ideally this workload is spawned and executed in response to a HTTP call from a web service. Appreciate your help and any pointers.

Comment: Containerize is always a good idea. However, there is no managed service able to host container and GPU capable, and which answer to HTTP request. You have to use GKE  with a NodePool with GPU (and with Cloud Run for Anthos to have a similar HTTP responsiveness experience), or deploy your container directly on a VM instance with a GPU.

Comment: I think that your question is too broad, I wanted to share this pages with you:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer